# Maximum value of $\frac{x}{y+1}+\frac{y}{x+1}$ while $0\leq x,y \leq 1$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

What is the maximum value of $\frac{x}{y+1}+\frac{y}{x+1}$ while $0\leq x,y \leq 1$? 

Wolfram Alpha plots this expression on a 3d graph, but I want to solve it algebraicly, by modifying the expression
**My Attempts**
1) add and substract 2 at the equation and we get $\frac{x+y+1}{y+1}+\frac{x+y+1}{x+1}$ and the numerator is same
=>failed
2) use AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
=>also failed

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ both vary from $0$ to $1$ you can use one variable calculus. First maximize over $x$ and then over $y$.

Comment: The function is convex in both variables, so that the maximum is attained at one of the corners of the quadrilateral.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When $ 0\le x,y \le 1$, then
$$\frac{x}{y+1} \le \frac{x}{x+y}$$
$$\frac{y}{x+1} \le \frac{y}{x+y}$$
Adding them we have
$$\frac{x}{y+1}+\frac{y}{x+1} \le  \frac{x+y}{x+y}=1.$$

Equality holds when $x=0$ and $y=1$ or $x=1$ and $y=0$ and the maximum of $1$ is attained.

Answer (score 3):

It is $$\frac{x}{y+1}+\frac{y}{x+1}\le 1$$ since
$$x(x+1)+y(y+1)\le (x+1)(y+1)$$ This is equivalent to
$$0\le x(1-x)+(1-y)(1-x+y)$$

Comment: Why is $ x(x+1)+y(y+1)\le (x+1)(y+1)$?

Comment: $\frac{x}{\color{#25f}{y+1}}+\frac{y}{\color{#d05}{x+1}}\le 1 \implies x\color{#d05}{(x+1)}+y\color{#25f}{(y+1)}\le\color{#d05}{(x+1)}\color{#25f}{(y+1)}$

Comment: You must say that value $1$ is actually obtained for $x=y=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Given the function $f : \mathcal{D} \to \mathbb{R}$ of law:

$$
f(x,\,y) := \frac{x}{y + 1} + \frac{y}{x + 1}\,,
$$

with $\mathcal{D} := [0,\,1] \times [0,\,1]$, since:

$$
\nabla f(x,\,y) = \left(\frac{1}{y + 1} - \frac{y}{\left(x + 1\right)^2}, \; \frac{1}{x + 1} - \frac{x}{\left(y + 1\right)^2}\right) \ne (0,\,0) \; \; \forall \, (x,\,y) \in D
$$

it follows that f has no critical points inside $\mathcal{D}$.

So, studying $f$ on the boundary of $\mathcal{D}$, noting that:

$$
f'(0,\,t) = f'(t,\,0) = 1\,, \; \; \; f'(1,\,t) = f'(t,\,1) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{(t + 1)^2}
$$

with $0 < t < 1$, $f$ has two critical points of coordinates $\left(1,\,\sqrt{2}-1\right)$, $\left(\sqrt{2}-1, \; 1\right)$, to which must be added the critical points placed in the four vertices of $\mathcal{D}$: $(0,\,0)$, $(1,\,0)$, $(1,\,1)$, $(0,\,1)$. This done, noting that:

$$
f\left(1,\,\sqrt{2}-1\right) = f\left(\sqrt{2}-1,\,1\right) = \sqrt{2} - \frac{1}{2}, \\ f(0,\,0) = 0, \; \; f(1,\,0) = f(1,\,1) = f(0,\,1) = 1
$$

since $f$ is a continuous function in $\mathcal{D}$, set closed and bounded, by *Weierstrass's theorem*:

$$
\underset{\mathcal{D}}{\min} f = 0 \; \; \; \; \; \; \underset{\mathcal{D}}{\max} f = 1
$$

as easily verifiable also in *Wolfram Mathematica* by the following code:

```
DensityPlot[x/(y + 1) + y/(x + 1), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
            FrameLabel -> {x, y}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
\delta\left(\frac{x}{y+1}+\frac{y}{x+1}\right)
=\left(\frac1{y+1}-\frac{y}{(x+1)^2}\right)\delta x
+\left(\frac1{x+1}-\frac{x}{(y+1)^2}\right)\delta y
$$
to get an interior critical point, we need
$$
\frac1{y+1}=\frac{y}{(x+1)^2}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac1{x+1}=\frac{x}{(y+1)^2}
$$
which have only the singular solution $x=y=-1$, which, even if allowed, are outside of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Therefore, we are searching for boundary critical points.

Due to the symmetry, we need only consider $x=0$ and $x=1$.

For $x=0$, we get $\frac{x}{y+1}+\frac{y}{x+1}=y$ and the maximum is at $y=1$.

For $x=1$, we get $\frac{x}{y+1}+\frac{y}{x+1}=\frac1{y+1}+\frac y2$. Then, the critical point is $y=\sqrt2-1$, which gives $\frac{x}{y+1}+\frac{y}{x+1}=\sqrt2-\frac12\lt1$. The endpoints $y\in\{0,1\}$ both give $\frac{x}{y+1}+\frac{y}{x+1}=1$.

Thus, the maximum is $1$.