# What is the maximum value of $\frac{7x+2y}{2x+2}+\frac{3x+8y}{2y+2}$ while $0≤x,y≤1$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

> Find  maximum value of $\left(\dfrac{7x+2y}{2x+2}+\dfrac{3x+8y}{2y+2}\right)$ for $0≤x,y≤1$

My approach was to use A.M-G.M inequality or cauchy shbert inequality, but I failed.

Comment: The same “trick” as in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3476058/42969 to your previous question works here: Decrease both denominators to $2x + 2y$.

Comment: oh. I see. Then the answer would be 5.

Comment: Should I delete the question, or answer it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution myself with helps of the comments above on the  question.
The solution is similar with [this solution of my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3476058/642064).
Since $x,y\leq1$
$$\dfrac{7x+2y}{2x+2}\leq\dfrac{7x+2y}{2x+2y}\\
\dfrac{3x+8y}{2y+2}\leq\dfrac{3x+8y}{2x+2y}$$
so
$$
\dfrac{7x+2y}{2x+2}+\dfrac{3x+8y}{2y+2}\leq\dfrac{10x+10y}{2x+2y}=5$$

Equality will hold when $x=1$ & $y=1$

Comment: One small point is you only showed that $5$ is an upper bound. For a complete answer, since the question asks for the maximum value, you need to show this value can actually reached. Note this is done for the case in your linked answer. For the case here, the value of $5$ occurs, for example, when $x = y = 1$, so you should explicitly mention this.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I see. I will edit the answer in that way.

Answer (score 2):

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{7x+2y}{2x+2} + \frac{3x+8y}{2y+2} 
= 
\left( \frac 72 - \frac{7-2y}{2x+2} \right)+ 
\left( 4 - \frac{8 - 3x}{2y+2} \right)
$$
is *strictly increasing* in both variables on $[0, 1]^2$, therefore
$$
 f(x, y) \le f(1,1) = 5
$$
with equality exactly for $(x, y) = (1,1)$.